# how to update only selected mysql database entries without messing up earlier ones

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I really need some help here, I need to be able to update only select parts of the database without messing any earlier entries. This code does populate the database but it ends up messing with earlier entries

```
$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST)){
 $v_fname = ((isset($_POST['v_fname']))?sanitize($_POST['v_fname']):'');
 $v_lname = ((isset($_POST['v_lname']))?sanitize($_POST['v_lname']):'');
 $v_dob = ((isset($_POST['v_dob']))?sanitize($_POST['v_dob']):'');
 $v_country = ((isset($_POST['v_country']))?
 sanitize($_POST['v_country']):'');

 $v_city = ((isset($_POST['v_city']))?sanitize($_POST['v_city']):'');

 $v_phone = ((isset($_POST['v_phone']))?sanitize($_POST['v_phone']):'');

 $v_bio = ((isset($_POST['v_bio']))?sanitize($_POST['v_bio']):'');


if($v_bio == "" && $v_phone == "" && $v_city == "" && $v_fname == "" && 
 $v_lname == ""&& $v_country == "" ){
 $errors = "Please Fill all the details";

}
if(!empty($errors)){
//echo display_errors($errors);

}else{


$db-> query("UPDATE `vendors` SET `v_phone` = '$v_phone', `v_fname` 
='$v_fname', `v_bio` = '$v_bio', `v_location` = '$v_city', `v_country` = 
'$v_country', `v_dob` = '$v_dob', `v_lname` = '$v_lname' WHERE v_id = 
'$v_id'");
echo $v_id;

}
}
```

This is the profile I wish to update. I want users to be able to optionally make entries

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to set **`$v_id`**

I do not see it in your code

Comment: I am getting $v_id from $_GET and using it to update the database. The issue is if a user, when filling the form, forgets or otherwise ignores some fields, the previous entries associated with the said fields in the database are essentially 'blanked out'

Comment: What method do you use to submit your form? You can not **`GET`** and **`POST`** methods at once. If you have **`$_GET[ 'v_id' ]`** value (not shown in your code), it means your form submitted by **`GET`** method and all of your **`$_POST[ ]`** data are empty. Try to change all **`$_POST`** with **`$_GET`** in your code instead, or change your form's method to **`POST`** and get your **`$v_id`** with **`$_POST`** also

Comment: Sorry, the `$v_id` variable identifies the user.  I get it via a `$_SESSION` variable:  `$v_id = $_SESSION['v_id']`

Comment: can your show me your complete code and also your form (just edit your question)